# How to use UISwitch with NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

```
 defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSLog(@"%@",[defaults objectForKey:@"firsttime"])

if([[defaults objectForKey:@"firsttime"]isEqualToString:@"YES"])
{
    UISwitch *onoff = (UISwitch *) sender;
    if(onoff.on)
    {
        NSLog(@"yes on1 facebookswitch");
        facebookSwitch.on = YES;
        [userDefault setValue:@"true" forKey:@"facebooknotify"];

        NSLog(@"on");
        if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
            [validate alertCommonWithoutMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"val_message",nil) :NSLocalizedString(@"val_facebook_login",nil) :@"OK"];
            facebookSwitch.on = YES;
            NSLog(@"yes on2 facebookswitch");

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"val_facebook_conf");
            [validate alertCommonWithoutMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"val_message",nil) :NSLocalizedString(@"val_facebook_conf",nil) :@"OK"];
            facebookSwitch.on = NO;
            [userDefault setValue:@"false" forKey:@"facebooknotify"];
            NSLog(@"yes off1 facebookswitch");
```

I'm using this method,but sumtimes the response is null.

Comment: be specific **but sumtimes the response is null.**

Comment: Try to post complete code, it is meaningless to leave a few lines of code.

Comment: How is the value for `firsttime` set? Are you talking about a `UISwitch` in the settings bundle? What exactly is your issue? What part of the posted code is giving you problems?

Comment: `[userDefault synchronize];` is missing from your code.. Any by the way what is null?

Comment: @iphonic Why is it missing? It's not needed since no value is being set in `NSUserDefaults`. And even if a value is being set, it's still not required.

Comment: BTW - why are you using strings to track boolean values?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes it seems from the name of the variable `userDefaults` that its a NSUserDefault variable, but the code itself is incomplete, its just guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
// add this code in your switch touch event
- (IBAction)YourSwitch:(UISwitch*)sender
{
    if (UISwitch.on)
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setBool:true forKey:@"Sound"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
    else
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setBool:false forKey:@"Sound"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
}

// add this code in your viewDidload .
BOOL isSound= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Sound"];

if (isSound){
    _ref_slider.on=TRUE;
} else {
    _ref_slider.on=FALSE;
}
```

i hope this code is useful for you.

Comment: @rmaddy just i am using a string for simple understanding of how to use userdefault.

Comment: Showing a newbie how to use things inappropriately doesn't really help with their understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As to why it's not working, the most common problem is `[userDefault synchronize]`

Also, rather than using string boolean values, why not use:

```
[userDefault setBool:YES forKey:@"facebooknotify"];
```

and then access by

```
BOOL notified = [userDefault boolForKey:@"facebooknotify"];
```

Comment: This answer is premature since we don't know what `userDefault` is. The OP doesn't show what it is in the code. We know that `defaults` is `NSUserDefaults` but we don't see the declaration of `userDefault`.

Comment: Ah, I misread...didn't make the distinction between variable names. I had read as ````userDefault```` and ````defaults```` being one and the same.

Comment: I'm passing values statically...so i've to pass the value through the object..if I use BOOL,How can I pass the value

Comment: In what way do you mean 'passing the values statically'? As instance variables?
In Obj-C you can use a BOOL as a variable, instance variable, @property etc just as with any Obj-C object, except no pointer obviously.